# use grep to return list of matching words in a line per file

Tags: grep

I have a list of files, and I want to look for some specific keywords in those files. The output should be a line for each file with matches, showing the words that we found just once. For example, if I have the following file test.txt

```
one,two,three
four,five,six,
seven,eight,nine
```

and i do a grep of the words  five and eight, it should return something like this:

```
test.txt:five,eight
```

I'm not interested in the lines, or the number of matches. I just want to know which words matched in each file. How can I do that?

Comment: you'll have to add your own attempts to solve this... and I don't think grep is a good choice.. as you are searching multiple files, change the question to include at least two files and relevant output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU ***grep*** + ***awk*** solution:

Let's say we have file `test1.txt` with contents:

```
one,two,three
four,five,six,
seven,eight,nine
```

and `test2.txt` with contents:

```
one
two
three, four, five
```

Finding matches for words `five` and `eight`:

```
grep -Hwo '\(five\|eight\)' test* 
| awk -F':' '{ a[$1]=(a[$1])? a[$1]","$2:$2 }END{ for(i in a) print i FS a[i] }'
```

The output:

```
test1.txt:five,eight
test2.txt:five
```

---

***grep*** details:

- `-H` - Print the file name for each match
- `-w` - Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words
- `-o` - Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines

***awk*** details:

- `-F':'` - field separator
- `a[$1]=(a[$1])? a[$1]","$2:$2` - using filename `$1` as array key for accumulating all matched words